# Apache Cordova listens event too late on ios after action

Tags: ios, cordova

I develop iOS app with Apache Cordova on Xcode. The problem is when I test my app on device, Cordova listens events too late. For example, when I click share button on iOS, the share box runs after 2 minutes. Another example is I use admob pro pluginfor admob, the ads run after 5 minutes on device ready.  I recognized that this problem is exist only on Cordova and its plugins events.

I checked and tried everything but couldn't find a solution. On android platform everything is work fine.

How can I fix this? Is there anybody can help me ?

Comment: Can you share an example code snippet that does this? Also, two questions: (1) Is the deviceReady event firing after 2-5 minutes, or is the admob responding after that 2-5 minutes (in other words, where is the delay)? -- (2) Are you running in an ios emulator or on an actual device?

Answer (score 0):

the admob responding after 2-5 minutes. I did type simple javascript function that is alert for device ready. its working fine.

the code snippet is below;

```
function reklamYukle() {
    var admobid = {};
    // TODO: replace the following ad units with your own
    if (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        admobid = { // for Android
            banner: 'ca-app-pub-5534669392136777/3711456161',
            interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-5534669392134577/5454702358'
        };
    } else if (/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        admobid = { // for iOS
            banner: 'ca-app-pub-5534669392136777/7457497261',
            interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-5534669392136777/5896501200'
        };
    } else {
        admobid = { // for Windows Phone
            banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/8878394753'
        };
    }

    AdMob.createBanner({
        adId: admobid.banner,
        position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
        overlap: false,
        offsetTopBar: true,
        bgColor: 'black',
        autoshow: true
    });

    AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
        adId: admobid.interstitial,
        autoShow: true
    });
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    reklamYukle();
}
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```